# Issue with CQN registration getting dropped implictly

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface, query-notifications

Using custom C++ OCI wrappers, I can successful register a CQN C++ callback-based registration, but it appears that somehow the subscription is dropped right away, *behind my back*. I get no call back on simple DMLs. If I try to unregister that subscription, for which register() worked just fine, I get **ORA-29970: Specified registration id does not exist**.

I'm running this test on a Win7 (64-bit) box, running a local 11.2.0.1.0 Oracle Server, and I connect with a C++ client app built against instantclient-11.2.0.2.0 that runs on that same machine.

- I tried setting **OCI_ATTR_SUBSCR_TIMEOUT** explicitly to 0, to no avail.
- I checked the **job_queue_processes** instance param to make sure it's not 0 (it's 1000).
- Of course, the user/schema I'm connecting with has been granted **CHANGE NOTIFICATION**

I'm running out of ideas on this issue, and I would appreciate some insights on what else I could try or check.

I'm starting to wonder if CQN needs to be *activated* somehow. My DBA skills are close to nonexistent, this is a stock install of 11gR1 on Windows using the installer, with no special configurations or customization done at all.

Thanks, --DD

**Update #1**

A colleague successfully ran that same test, and he ran it using the server-provided oci.dll. I tried that (I build using instantclient, but forced the PATH at runtime: `Path=D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN;$(Path)` in VS Property Page> Debugging> Environment), and indeed the CQN test works! We still haven't figured out whether <strike>the slight version difference between client and server, or</strike> using instantclient (the *Light* variant by the way) vs a full client vs a server install is the real culprit.

But it is bad news that <strike>a newer</strike> instantclient does not support CQN...

**Update #2**

I've tried all 6 combinations of instantclient *Light* (65 MB) or *Normal* (150 MB) in versions 12.2.0.(1|2|3).0 on Win64, and none of them worked. Haven't tested the Full Client yet, nor have we tested on Linux just yet.

```
Environment_var cqn_env = Environment::create(OCI_EVENTS + OCI_OBJECT);
Connection_var cqn_conn = Connection::logon2(...);
Subscription sub(cqn_conn, "cqn_test", OCI_SUBSCR_NAMESPACE_DBCHANGE);
sub.set<attr::SUBSCR_CALLBACK>( &cqn_callback_func );
sub.set<attr::SUBSCR_CQ_QOSFLAGS>( OCI_SUBSCR_CQ_QOS_QUERY );

try {
    sub.register_self();
} catch (const OracleException& ex) {
    BOOST_REQUIRE(ex.error_code && *ex.error_code == 29972);
    cerr << "\nSKIPPED: test requires CHANGE NOTIFICATION privilege" << endl;
    return;
}
```